# Generating random points inside polygons that capture values from multiple attribute fields

Tags: qgis

I have some census block data where one attribute field is a total count (let's say number of homes), and then additional attribute fields disaggregate counts in different categories (e.g. home value might have 5 bins: 50k-100k, 100k-150k, etc...). I'd like to create a shp file in QGIS that generates random points for each home in each block polygon but also retains the attribute name of the disaggregated counts as a value in a new attribute field. EG, each point would have a new categorical attribute called "home_value" with a value like 50-100k or 100k-150k.

I think I could do this by generating a different layer for each attribute using "random points inside polygons (variable)" and then merging the layers, but I'm hoping there is some easier way.

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to visualize your problem. What do you mean by "additional attribute disaggregate counts in different categories"? Are you saying that there are duplicate polygons for information about different housing categories? Why are you trying to create random points for houses inside the census blocks? And in any case, using the "Random Points inside Polygons" tool in about as simple as it gets for generating random points so I'm not sure what else you could be hoping for.

Comment: Once you've generated the points, is it possible to do a spatial overlay to get the attributes from the polygons into the points? Or is there something preventing that?