# Retaining polygon feature attributes in points randomly generated within using QGIS

Tags: qgis

How do I  retain polygon feature attributes in random points generated within these polygons using QGIS?

Like [Generating random points inside polygons that capture values from multiple attribute fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282145), I found that QGIS 3.14 "Random Points inside Polygons" tool does not retain any attributes from the polygon features.

Comment: A spatial join should be an easy workaround.

Comment: It would work in some cases but it would not work if there are overlapping bounding geometries used to generate the random points.

Answer (score 2):

For built-in solution, you need to wait for QGIS 3.16 because of this PR https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35745 (C++ implementation)

I've already made an addition to existing Python processing script as mentioned in [QGIS Random Points in Polygon PRESERVING Attribute Table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361885/qgis-random-points-in-polygon-preserving-attribute-table) for this intent (PS: stop using it when QGIS 3.16 will land). Only useful to avoid waiting.